# C++: invalid conversion from 'int' to 'int*'

Tags: c++

I have the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void A(int m, int array[]) {
    int change=array[0];
    for (int i=0; i<m; i++) {
        array[i]=array[i+1];
    }
    array[m-1]=change;
}

void B(int m, int array[]) {
    int change=array[1];
    for (int i=1; i<m; i++) {
        array[i]=array[i+1];
    }
    array[m-1]=change;
}

int main() {
    int m,k; cin>>m>>k;
    int array[m]={0};
    for (int i=0; i<m; i++) {
        array[i]=i;
    }
    char movecard[100000];
    cin.getline(movecard,100000,'.');
    for (int i=0; i<100000; i++) {
        if (movecard[i]=='A') {
            A(m,array[m]);
        }
        if (movecard[i]=='B') {
            B(m,array[m]);
        }
    }
    cout<<array[k-1]<<array[k]<<array[k+1];
    return 0;
}
```

However, the compiler returns an error:

```
invalid conversion from 'int' to 'int*'
```

I did not use pointers at all, why would this error come out? What is wrong with my code, and how can I fix it?

Comment: I wish you would post the entire context of the error message, which also shows what line it happens on.  Instead I had to read your program until I found calls like `A(m,array[m])`, where you are passing a single `int` value as the second parameter, which is expecting an array.

Comment: `A(m,array[m])` should be `A(m,array)`.  Same with the call to `B`.  Voting to close this question as being related to a typo.

Comment: " the compiler returns an error" Okay; did you look at anything else in the error message, for example, the line and character number where it said the error happened? "I did not use pointers at all" Yes, you did; all these `int array[]` in your function signatures mean the same thing as `int* array`. Anyway, it would help if you explain what the code is supposed to do, and what the context is. How does an array of integers represent "cards", and why are you shuffling them around in this way?

Comment: Also note that variable-length arrays are non-standard in C++.  They're also dangerous.  Don't use them.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In both of your function calls you are passing a value present in the array, in function definition it's array declaration which is more or less pointer only. Try sending the array by reference and it will work.
change this ->

B(m,array[m]);

to this

B(m,array);

Comment: a code snippets would evlt. helping more (and faster).